# Why does executing "cmd" command in PowerShell via my C# application freezes it?

Tags: c#, powershell

## **Context:**

I'm creating an application where the user has the possibility of executing PowerShell commands through my .NET app.

## **Situation**:

I created the following method:

```
public static string ExecutePowerShell(string cmd, out string errors)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(cmd);

        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
        {
            output.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        errors = string.Join("\n", PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.ReadAll());
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
string errors = String.Empty;

ExecutePowerShell("cmd", out errors);
```

## **Expected output:**

This is what I'd find if I execute it in a PowerShell console:

[image: Screenshot]

## **Output:**

My application just freezes.

## **Steps to reproduce:**

Here's a complete code to reproduce the problem: [Link to Pastebin for organization](http://pastebin.com/raw/Jh87mhQx)

***Don't forget to add a reference to `System.Management.Automation` assembly (usually at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0`)**

In the above code, I've put breakpoints at both `Console.WriteLine` calls, but none of them is reached. Obviously, nothing is printed on screen either.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: When you run it in the console, you're launching a nested command shell, using `cmd` rather than powershell. I think `Invoke` would wait for whatever you run to exit before returning, which isn't what `cmd` does (note that the second prompt in your screenshot isn't the *powershell* prompt, but the `cmd` one instead) - it's waiting for new command input.

Comment: Your cmd isnt told to end, so its waiting for it to end

Comment: Because cmd doesn't return/exit without user input - run `cmd /c` and it'll return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CMD` is, by default, an interactive program, and will wait for user input. If you wish `CMD` to return, either someone must type `EXIT` at the interactive prompt, or it must be invoked in batch mode with the `/C` switch and a command to execute - the `/C` tells `CMD` to execute the command, then return.

Your C# program does not hang when you change `CMD` to `IPCONFIG` because `IPCONFIG` is not an interactive program and does not wait for input from the user.

It would be helpful if you could update your question to explain what you are actually trying to accomplish by invoking `CMD`.

Comment: Oh, so instead of returning whats is shown on the screenshot it was starting a new instance of Command Prompt. Thank you for explaining me. btw, I wasn't trying to accomplish anything, was just testing the method to see if it works as expected. Thanks again!